# 18.04 server remastered ISO preseed finish-install "left unconfigured"

Tags: server, system-installation, preseed

I have a remastered install ISO based on ubuntu-18.04-server-amd64.iso with a preseed which is failing the final step in the installer.
The `late_command` script runs successfully, but the installer ends up on the main menu with no option to reboot.

Here is the last logs after the `late_command` runs:

```
Jul 25 19:15:36 finish-install: info: Running /usr/lib/finish-install.d/07speakup
Jul 25 19:15:36 finish-install: info: Running /usr/lib/finish-install.d/10apt-cdrom-setup
Jul 25 19:15:36 finish-install: /usr/lib/finish-install.d/10apt-cdrom-setup backed up
Jul 25 19:15:36 main-menu[289]: INFO: Menu item 'finish-install' succeeded but requested to be left unconfigured.
Jul 25 19:15:36 main-menu[289]: INFO: Falling back to the package description for cdrom-detect
Jul 25 19:15:36 main-menu[289]: INFO: Falling back to the package description for ethdetect
```

This seems to indicate that something in the `10apt-cdrom-setup` script returned abnormally, but I see nothing in there that should fail. Any body recognize something here or have any ideas where to look?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bypass this issue, I can't say it's really a fix since I never found the cause for certain.

In my preseed file my `late_command` was like so:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string /bin/sh -s /final/setup.sh
```

I included a `exit 0` line at the end of the script but something was still causing a failure status, even though all the commands in the script were successful.
Changing only the way the `late_command` is invoked made the `finish-install` scripts complete successfully.

```
d-i preseed/late_command string /bin/sh -c "$(cat /final/setup.sh); exit 0"
```